# How can I get an inset title for well in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for some styling and I am trying to replicate the group box with a title in it that Twitter Bootstrap uses on its documentation pages.

[image]

I can find the CSS, but there is obviously some JavaScript involved here to put the "Example" text into the DOM. Ideally what I would like is the ability to have a DIV which styles as the image but I supply the title such as "My Title" so that I can vary it from "Example".

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I missed the CSS class that actually added the content!! So if you want to achieve this result include the following CSS:

```
.group-example:after {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
    color: #9DA0A4;
    content: "Example";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: -1px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
}
.group-example {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 39px 19px 14px;
    position: relative;
}
```